# Multiple subclasses of same PFObject subclass causing errors

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have this very simple setup for my PFObject subclasses in Swift.

- Foo : PFObject
- Bar1 : Foo
- Bar2 : Foo

Here is what they look like in code:

Foo

```
import Foundation

class Foo : PFObject, PFSubclassing
{
    class func parseClassName() -> String!
    {
        return "Foo"
    }
}
```

Bar1

```
import Foundation

class Bar1 : Foo {}
```

Bar2

```
import Foundation

class Bar2 : Foo {}
```

AppDelegate `didFinishLaunching`

```
Foo.registerSubclass()
Bar1.registerSubclass()
Bar2.registerSubclass()
Parse.setApplicationId("APP_ID", clientKey: "CLIENT_KEY")
```

I then get this error at runtime:

```
Tried to register both _TtC9CardForge4Bar1 and _TtC9CardForge4Bar2 as the native 
PFObject subclass of Foo. Cannot determine the right class to use because neither 
inherits from the other.
```

It appears that I can't have multiple subclasses of one `PFObject` subclass, but I see nothing for that in the documentation. What is going on here? What is a native subclass?

Comment: I don't know if what you are doing is supported. However, I use a category on PFObject for common methods I want and then create subclasses for each object. That may get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. I don't understand where do you want to go by doing this.

I think the best approach for subclassing in parse is : one subclass for one table. The most important goal of subclassing for Parse is managing your properties. So copy ALL your custom properties to your custom class. And just register this subclass. After that you can create other subclass (not registered to parse) for methods or protecting your properties.

Answer (score 0):

As of Parse iOS SDK 1.6.2, I can confirm that you can have subclasses of subclasses of `PFObject` and they work just fine.

i.e. it's possible to have `class Foo : Bar`  and `class Bar : PFObject` and you can save objects of type `Foo` and query for them as well. It just works.